# Installing ceiling rack with a LPI32 Plus I Joist Framing.

Tags: ceiling

My garage ceiling has LPI I joists that are 11 7/8 deep and 24 inches on center. Wondering if I can install ceiling racks if the supports run perpendicular to the joists and span and are  secured to at least 2 joists.